# Excel macro to find and assign relative products (with similar features) to products

Tags: vba, excel, relationship

I have made a screenshot of a sheet so it will be easier to explain/understand:
[image]

So, as you see on each row of a Sheet1 has a product name (in red) and its features (to the right). There could be hundreds of products and random number of features for each. Many products (rows) have one or a few matching features, but some may have none.

I need some automated way to assign each product another 5 products (positioned by similarity) that are the most similar to that product. The more matched features products have, the more similar to a given product they are. So a product with 5 matches goes as 1st relative one, product with 4 - second, etc, but it may be that there will be no matches. Then it should get a random product assigned as a relative.

Here's a screenshot of a Sheet2, how I imagine the processed result should look like visually (but it doesn't match the logics, as I didn't manually pick the right relatives):
[image]

I have made an example Excel sheet, but i just built it out of my mind now and it may not be the perfect one to play with, here it is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69246594/related.xlsm

Is it possible at all for Excel macro to do that? If yes, how?

Comment: It would help if you can post the actual expected result. That way we can test if it is possible with VBA. My first guess would be yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code covers everything you need except for the random entry if no matches are found, in that case it will just return the last row that it has 0 matches with. I would advise putting this on `Sheet2` for the `Worksheet_Activate()` otherwise rename it and set it to a button or whatever you require.

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()

' Determine the max number of rows from Sheet1
Dim maxRows As Integer
maxRows = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Determine how many matches each row gets with the other rows
Dim matches()
ReDim matches(1 To maxRows, 1 To maxRows) ' Create the match hits as an array
For i = 1 To maxRows ' Loop over each row
    For j = 1 To maxRows ' Loop over each row again
        matches(i, j) = 0 ' Set all matches in the array to zero
        For k = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).End(xlToRight).Column ' Loop over columns for row i
            For l = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).End(xlToRight).Column ' Loop over columns for row j
                If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, k).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, l).Value Then ' If a match occurs
                    matches(i, j) = matches(i, j) + 1 ' Increase the counter by 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
    matches(i, i) = 0 ' Set self row matches to 0, else would get the row itself is highest match
Next

' Determine the top five matches
Dim maxValue, maxIndex As Integer
maxValue = 0
maxIndex = 0
For i = 1 To maxRows ' Loop over each row
    For j = 1 To 5 ' Required 5 matches
        For k = 1 To maxRows ' Loop over each row again
            If matches(i, k) > maxValue Then ' If to find the highest maxValue
                maxValue = matches(i, k) ' Set the maxValue
                maxIndex = k ' Set the index of the maxValue
             End If
        Next
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, j + 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(maxIndex, 1).Value ' Set the appropriate cell to highest hit
        matches(i, maxIndex) = 0 ' Set the index to 0 to avoid duplication in next loop iteration
        maxValue = 0 ' Reset for next loop
        maxIndex = 0 ' Reset for next loop
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Any further changes that you may need let me know. Included is also a walkthrough of each line.

Comment: thank you very much, it works as it should as far as I see. The only thing that could make it better was if it could process faster, as I'm affraid that with a thousand of rows and 50 columns it might not finish...